# Azure SQL DB hanging on to connection until EF times out

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have an intermittent issue that I can't seem to get to the bottom of whereby a .NET Framework 4.6 MVC API (C#) uses an Entity Framework 6 (runtime v4.0.30319) stored procedure call that takes a long time to respond.

The stored procedure is hosted on Azure SQL DB.

It is an unremarkable procedure, it interrogates a couple of tables to give a nutritionist their clients' latest data and website interactions.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [PORTAL].[GetNutritionistCustomers]

    @id_usernut varchar(20)

AS

    WITH Activity AS (
        SELECT LastActivity = MAX(ExecutionDate),
               ded.UserName
        FROM portal.DailyExecutionData ded
        WHERE ded.ExecutionDate < GETDATE()
        GROUP BY ded.UserName
    ),
    Logging AS (
        SELECT LastLogin = MAX(l.LoggedOnDate),
               l.UserName
        FROM PORTAL.Logins l
        WHERE l.LoginType = 'Direct Client'
        GROUP BY l.UserName
    )
    SELECT unc.CompanyCode,
           a.ACCOUNT,
           ad.ADDRESS1,
           un.ID_UserNut,
           ueu.ExpirationDate,
           Expired = CAST(CASE WHEN ueu.ExpirationDate < GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT),
           LastActive = la.LastActivity,
           l.LastLogin
    FROM UK_Nutritionist un
    JOIN UK_NutCompany unc ON un.ID_UserNut = unc.ID_UserNut
    JOIN UK_EnabledUsers ueu ON unc.CompanyCode = ueu.UserName
    JOIN Klogix.ACCOUNT a ON ueu.ID_User = a.ACCOUNTID
    LEFT JOIN Klogix.ADDRESS ad ON a.ADDRESSID = ad.ADDRESSID AND ad.IsPrimary = 1
    LEFT JOIN Activity la ON ueu.UserName = la.UserName
    LEFT JOIN Logging l ON ueu.UserName = l.UserName
    WHERE un.ID_UserNut = @id_usernut
```

Run in SSMS or ADS this procedure takes on average about 50-100ms to complete. This is consistent, the tables are well indexed and the query plan is all index seeks. There are no Key or RID lookup red flags.

Having investigated with profiler, I've determined that what happens is EF creates a connection, calls the procedure. I can see the RPC entered, EF reaches it connection timeout period, and then we get RPC completed, and the data returns to EF, and the code spins out a list of pocs to return to the caller in json.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Customers")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    try
    {
        if (IsTokenInvalid(Request))
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

        var nutritionistCustomers = new ExcdbEntities().GetNutritionistCustomers(TokenPayload.Nutritionist).Select(x => new NutritionistCustomers()
        {
            Account = x.ACCOUNT,
            Address = x.ADDRESS1,
            CompanyCode = x.CompanyCode,
            ExpirationDate = x.ExpirationDate,
            expired = x.Expired,
            LastActive = x.LastActive,
            LastLogin = x.LastLogin
            
        }).ToList();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, GenerateResponse(nutritionistCustomers))
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, GenerateResponse(e));
    }
}
```

If I change the timeout on the connection then the amount of time that SQL waits before releasing the data changes.

I thought it might be something to do with the Azure app service that hosts the API, but it turns out that running it in debug in Visual Studio has the same issue.

The short term fix is to recompile the stored procedure. This will then return the data immediately. But at some undetermined point in the future the same procedure will suddenly manifest this behaviour again.

Only this procedure does this, all other EF interactions, whether linq to sql table or view interrogations, and all other procedures seem to behave well.
This has happened before in a now legacy system that had the same architecture, though it was a different procedure on a different database.

Whilst shortening the timeout is a workaround, it's a system wide value, and even 10 seconds, enough to cope with system hiccouphs, is way too long for this customer selection screen, which should be instantaneous.
Also I would rather fix the underlying problem, if anyone has any clue what might be going on.

I have considered an OPTION_RECOMPILE on the statement, but it just feels wrong to do so.

If anyone else has experienced this and has any insight I'd be most grateful is it's driving me to distraction.

Comment: I added the EF context settings, scraped out of profiler, to the SSMS call.
I think the significant one is:
`set transaction isolation level read committed`
and when it's problematic I get an uncommitted transaction warning in SSMS and I think it's this that is waiting for locks to resolve.
I'm not sure what is causing that, perhaps an issue with an ADF pipeline?
Anyhoo, I've set transaction isolation level read to uncommitted in the compile context of the proc itself. Hacky but its doing the trick. Now I need to investigate the real cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end this turned out to be a concatenation issue.
EF sets the CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL off inits context, and for whatever reason this caused a truly terrible performance issue.

For what I can only call legacy issue of inept previous employees, a date returned by the procedure did some inexplicable chopping up and concatenation of various dateparts of a date.

I replaced this by, you know, returning the date (and amending the EF object obviously), and hey presto no more performance issue.